# angular empty array outside observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

in my angular application I have the following code inside a method:

```
let cardArray: string[] = [];

this.cardService.getCards().subscribe((cards) => {
  console.log("1", cards);

  for (const card of cards.cards) {
    cardArray.push(card.id);
  }

  console.log("2", cardArray);
});

console.log("3", cardArray);
```

The problem is, that 3 is logged before 1 and 2, so outside the observable the array it empty, inside it is filled. How can I achieve the data outside the observable? I need to use it at the end of my function.

Greetings!

**EDIT:** Added code

```
let cardArray: string[] = [];

this.cardService.getCards().subscribe((cards) => {
  cardArray = cards.cards;
});

return this.http.post<Object>(
  url,
  {
    cards: cardArray // <-- here the array is empty
  },
  {
    headers: headers
  }
);
```

Comment: This is an issue with asynchronous operations. If you want to execute some code using `cardArray` data, you should do that inside function you pass to subscribe method.

Comment: You are working with Observable it is asynchronous, Please provide what are you willing to do instead of the console.log("3"....)?

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with more code.

Comment: As Liam answer you should call your Api inside the subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your code. It should be more like:

```js
this.cardService.getCards()
.pipe(
   mergeMap((cards) => {
      return this.http.post<Object>(
        url,
       {
          cards: cards
       },
       {
          headers: headers
       }
     );
   })
)
.subscribe();
```

Here I'm using [RXJS mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) to pipe the result of the first observable into the second. **Note** this is STILL async so you can't just return the result. If you want to consume this higher up I'd suggest something more like:

```js
function postCards(): Observable<Object> {
   return this.cardService.getCards()
    .pipe(
       mergeMap((cards) => {
         return this.http.post<Object>(
            url,
            {
              cards: cards
            },
           {
              headers: headers
           }
        );
     })
   );

}


postCards().subscribe();
```

You should read more about [RXJS operators](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators)

---

> Is there a way to get create an array only with the IDs coming from the getCards method in this example

Well, yes and no. You should read [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). Basically your thinking about it wrong. Don't think synchronously, you need to start thinking async.

> Embrace the asynchronous nature of JavaScript! While certain
> asynchronous operations provide synchronous counterparts (so does
> "Ajax"), it's generally discouraged to use them, especially in a
> browser context.
>
> Why is it bad do you ask?
>
> JavaScript runs in the UI thread of the browser and any long-running
> process will lock the UI, making it unresponsive. Additionally, there
> is an upper limit on the execution time for JavaScript and the browser
> will ask the user whether to continue the execution or not.

There are [various async solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular) to your problem, the right one will depend on what you actually want to do with this array.